I frequently have thoughts about my beloved who died few years ago
I want to ask my grandmother died few years back and still whenever I thought about her by any means, i start crying whilst missing her and always feels heavy heartedness because of her loss. And very frequently her memory reflects and dominates my thought. I literally have no eagerness to live and want to meet her after death as soon as possible?
Alhamdulillah I have every in life.
However I miss her abundant because of that I no longer fond of this life riches and twists. Feeling like dying heart. No materialistic pleasure whatsoever. Thought always prevailing about her. Please help if anyone has answers from legit sources like Al Quran and the Hadith.
